# jQuery Masonry Not Rendering Rails 3 One Month Rails

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have ben trying to implement jQuery Masonry and it keeps not working.

It errors out and in the browser console it says this.

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'

Masonry is in the Vendor/assest/javascripts

Okay here are my files.

skills.js.coffee :

```
jQuery ->
  $('#skills_page').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#skills_page').masonry itemSelector: ".box"
```

index.html.haml

```
.container
  #skills_page
    = render @skills

= will_paginate @skills
```

custon.css.scss

```
.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 214px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 100px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .375);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 100px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.375);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .375);
  display: block;

}
.box img {
    diplay: block;
    width: 100%;

}

.description {
    margin: 10px 0 5px;
}
```

_skill.html.haml

```
.box
  .pin_container
    - if skill.image.file?
      .pin_image_bkg= image_tag(skill.image(:long)) 
    - else
      .pin_image_bkg= image_tag "214by70.png"
    - if skill.user.profile_pic.file?
      .pin_image= image_tag(skill.user.profile_pic(:medium), :style => "-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 7px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;")
    - else
      .pin_image= image_tag("default_avatar.png", :style => "-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 7px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;")
    .pin_btn= link_to 'View', skill, :class => "btn"
  .pin_subtitle 
    Help Package from
    =link_to "#{skill.user.name}" , skill.user
  .pin_title
    =link_to "#{skill.title}", skill
  .mini_info
    -unless skill.work_hrs.blank?
      .left
        .mini_hours= skill.work_hrs
      .left
        .mini_title W
    -unless skill.meeting_hrs.blank?
      .left
        .mini_hours= skill.meeting_hrs
      .left
        .mini_title M
      .clear
```

Here is what my scripts look like when you view the page source :)

```
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.masonry.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/applications.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/password_resets.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/skills.js?body=1"
```

Comment: And you've placed this in a document ready function? What's the order of your files included in your header? If `skills.js.coffee` doesn't come **after** `masonry.js`, then you won't be able to access it. Also, you should use a `$(document).ready(function(){` to ensure nothing execues before the DOM is available to you. I'm not familiar with coffee.js, so perhaps that's what `jQuery ->` does. Either way, check inclusion order. Also, check console for errors.

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy.  I checked the order of the js and it looks okay.  The only console error is 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'

Comment: I am fine doing the .js version instead of the .js.coffee but I guess I don't know how to do it, do I just make a file in the assets/javascript folder like skillstyle.js  then put the '$(document).ready(function(){' in it?  I am using rails 3.  Thanks so much for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns our this was a stupid one :)

In my applications layout I had this at the bottome :

```
        :plain

      <!-- jQuery via Google + local fallback, see h5bp.com -->

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

      <!-- Bootstrap jQuery Plugins, compiled and minified -->

      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

    :plain

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And that broke everything :)

Deleted that and it was all good :)

Sorry for asking a stupid question!

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is working properly then it looks like the masonry plugin isn't loading correctly, hence the 'method unavailable' error. I have thrown together a  basic [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tenoversix/JDgEk/81/)... sans coffescript, and it seems to work correctly.

Make sure to include jQuery first and then the Masonry plugin.

The JS / jQuery should look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $skills_page = $('#skills_page');

    $skills_page.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $skills_page.masonry({
            // options
            itemSelector: '.box',
            columnWidth: 200
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.js file

Is jquery being called there?

Your application.js file (under assets) should look something like this
http://screencast.com/t/CwM2FRlGaVs